# jQuery - Zoom DIV (and its contents) on hover, and set opacity of other DIVs

Tags: jquery, zooming, fadeout, onhover

I have 4 DIVs with the same class, ".category-container" and basically what I need to do, is zoom the entire DIV and everything in it when its hovered over, so say 120%.   When one of them is hovered over with the zoom effect, the other 3 need to fade out to 50% opacity.

I know how to do the zoom part, but I'm a little stuck on getting the fadeout to occur in the other 3 divs when one of them is zoomed on hover.

Hope this makes sense - can anyone help?

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.category-container').bind('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
    $('.category-container').not('.hover').fadeTo('normal',0.2);
});
$('.category-container').bind('mouseout',function() {
    $('.category-container').removeClass('hover').fadeTo('normal',1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8fvJN/ Here you go